# Is there a function analytic in $D(0,r)$ such that $(f(z))^2 = e^z + z$ for all $z\in D(0,r)$?

Tags: complex-analysis, analytic-functions, multivalued-functions

I'm stuck on the following problem:

Let $D = \{z\in\mathbb{C}:|z|<r\}$, $r>0$. Is there a function analytic in $D$ such that $(f(z))^2 = e^z + z$ for all $z\in D$? Look at the two cases:

1. $r = 1$
2. $r = \frac{1}{2}$

I first wrote that for such a function, $$f(z) = (e^z + z)^{\frac{1}{2}} = e^{\frac{1}{2}\log(e^z + z)}$$ Then $f$ is analytic where $\log(e^z + z)$ is analytic. So my guess at the answer is that for the second case ($r=\frac{1}{2}$), $f$ is analytic in this disk because I can make a branch cut and make $\log(e^z + z)$ a single-valued function; and for the first case ($r=1$), there may be no such branch I can take.

However, I'm unsure of how to show this last part rigorously: I did some playing around with $e^z+z$ and am guessing that for the second case ($r=\frac{1}{2}$), I may want to try to show that I can take the principal branch because (maybe) $e^z+z$ cannot attain negative values in this disk. But I'm not sure where to go from here, and not sure what to do for the first case ($r=1$). Thanks for any answers!

Comment: Since $\sqrt e < 2$ it is clear that $|e^z| > e^{-1/2} > |z|$ when $|z|<1/2$ so the function $e^z+z$ is non zero there and has analytic logarithm as the disc is simple connected; on the other hand there is a real simple ( derivative obviously non zero on the real line) zero of $e^z+z$ between $-1$ and $-1/2$ so there the function cannot be a holomoprhic square since those have zeroes of even multiplicity

Comment: @Conrad Thanks for your answer! I understand the $r=1$ case now. But for the $r=\frac{1}{2}$ case, I see now that $e^z+z$ has no zero for $z\in D$... But how are you concluding that it 'has analytic logarithm as the disk is simply connected'? Don't we have to ensure that the image of the disk under $e^z+z$ is simply connected, which doesn't seem necessarily true?

Comment: the image can be anything as long as it doesn;t contain zero and we are on a simply connected domain since then if for example, you fix a base point in the domain  (say $0$ here for simplicity), you can take $\log f(z)=\int_0^zf'(w)dw/f(w)$ as by simple connectedness, it doesn't matter which path you use to connect $0$ with $z$ so $\int_0^z$ is well defined (for example you take the segment $[0,z]$ here)

Comment: That makes sense! Thanks so much for your help!

Comment: Happy  to be of help